# How to get SQL COUNT to include results of zero?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to count the number of students in each class. The idea here is that there's different subjects at a school, and I want to view the numbers in each Photography class.

Enrolments is used to enrol a student into a class, so counting the students with a confirmed enrolment in each class returns the number of students in that class.

Classnumber is the unique ID of a class, studentnumber is unique to each student.

However, the count function i'm using doesn't return the classes which have no students. Is there an easy, or better way of achieving this?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
SELECT enrolment.classnumber, COUNT(studentnumber) AS "Students" FROM enrolment
JOIN class ON enrolment.classnumber=class.classnumber
WHERE enrolmentstatus='Confirmed'
AND classtype='Photography'
GROUP BY enrolment.classnumber
```

But it only returns the following:

```
CLASS NUMBER         Students
------------         --------
6                    5
```

Rather than including the other 3 empty photography classes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
SELECT c.classnumber, COUNT(e.studentnumber) AS Students
FROM class c LEFT JOIN
     enrolment e
     ON e.classnumber = c.classnumber AND
        e.enrolmentstatus = 'Confirmed'
WHERE c.classtype = 'Photography'
GROUP BY c.classnumber;
```

The idea is to start with `class` because that defines all the rows you want in the result set.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to bring in matching rows.  Conditions on the second table (such as status) need to be in the `ON` clause.

Comment: This is perfect Gordon. Thanks so much!